# Laravel 4 Versionable Package error: Class 'MyApp\Models\Eloquent' not found

Tags: laravel-4, revisionable

I'm trying to use the Versionable Package in my Laravel 4 app based on the new, trait based implementation like this

```
<?php


use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

namespace MyApp\Models;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use Venturecraft\Revisionable\Revisionable;
    ...
```

When i use this code above, I get this error

```
Class 'MyApp\Models\Eloquent' not found
```

I have also tried changing the namespace to app\models but it still shows the not found error.

Please could someone help me out here? I followed all the instructions on the Github page but as I'm new to Laravel, I may be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use either of the following solutions:

Change your class declaration to:

```
class User extends \Eloquent implements \UserInterface, \RemindableInterface
```

Or, simply remove the line:

```
namespace MyApp\Models;
```

I would recommend taking the second solution (removing the namespace) for now, until you are comfortable with namespaces in PHP.

Additionally, you should be using RevisionableTrait, not Revisionable, e.g.,

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must write fully qualified name for Eloquent

```
class User extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
```

Comment: Thank you @Masnug. Tried that but it shows a new error: Interface 'app\models\UserInterface' not found